# Django submit two forms within one view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to submit two forms within one view. First, a user shares a URL through the first form. My program then renders some graphs and will ask the user at the end of the page to fill out a form and submit it. Here's how I'm trying to solve it:

views.py:

```
if request == "POST":
    if 'first-input-name' in request.POST: # or in request.POST.get('name')
        # do something
    elseif 'second-input-name' in request.POST: # or in request.POST.get('name')
        # do something else
```

template:

```
<input type="submit" name="first-input-name"/>
<input type="submit" name="second-input-name"/>
```

This is the approach I found in answers to similar questions. However, in my `requests.POST` I don't find the name of my input, and therefore I don't get the expected behavior.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Try putting `value="first-input-name"` on your inputs, there's no data for the request.POST to send otherwise

Comment: First i would like to understand why you need two separate forms for this

Comment: @0sVoid thanks, `value="first-input-name"` seemed to help add the data to request.POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a better and less difficult approach, that is to create different action urls with related functions:

In template:

```
<form action="{% url 'view-1' %}">
    <input type="submit" name="first-input-name"/>
    # other...
</form>
<form action="{% url 'view-2' %}">
    <input type="submit" name="second-input-name"/>
    # other...
</form>
```

In urls:

```py
path(first/, first_view, name="view-1"),
path(second/, second_view, name="view-2"),
```

In views:

```py
def first_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #do something...

def second_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #do something...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just have one form with two fields to reduce code complexity. And do the below

```
def single_view(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    # i also advice you use underscore(AKA snake_case) instead of hyphens
    first_input_name = request.POST.get("first_input_name")
    second_input_name = request.POST.get("second_input_name")
```

This also mean in your inputs you will have `value="first_input_name"` and `value="second_input_name"` in your inputs

Comment: Thanks! Actually I don't think that this would work, because I think the inputs would need to be seperated. The first input is an URL, which I use to scrape some data and render plots. The second input is allowing the user to submit a form, telling me which of the plots they want me to print out for them (not literally, but it's the same logic). Not sure if you're proposed solution would work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should have two views: The first asks for the URL and then on submit, takes them to the second view, which then displays your graphs and has another form for followup action.